# How can we identify all the modules belongs to a given distribution

Tags: perl

How can we identify all the modules belongs to a given distribution.

e.g. the XML::LibXML distribution provides a set of following modules
https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML

How can we get this list either through cpan/ppm or through any standard per packages.

Actually we are writing a unit test framework for our code written in Perl. To verify the module, we need a way to find the distribution name for a given module name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MetaCPAN API provides a solution to this problem with a JSON web service (http://api.metacpan.org).

It's easy to try different queries using `curl` on the command line or via the web form at http://explorer.metacpan.org/

If you know the name of the release you're searching for,
you can do a query like this to get a list of module names:

```
/module/_search
{
  "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
  "size" : 1000,
  "fields" : [ "module.name" ],
  "filter" : {
    "and": [
      { "term" : { "module.authorized" : true } },
      { "term" : { "module.indexed" : true } },
      { "term" : { "release" : "XML-LibXML-1.95" } },
      { "term" : { "status" : "latest" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

You could also substitute `"release": "XML-LibXML-1.95"` with `"distribution": "XML-LibXML"`.

If you are starting with a module name and need to determine the name of the release first, try this:

```
/module/_search
{
  "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
  "size" : 1000,
  "fields" : [ "release", "distribution" ],
  "filter" : {
    "and": [
      { "term" : { "module.name" : "XML::LibXML" } },
      { "term" : { "status" : "latest" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

That query syntax is the ElasticSearch DSL since the api uses ElasticSearch to index the data.

To do query from perl there is a [MetaCPAN::API](https://metacpan.org/module/MetaCPAN::API)
module, though I have not used it myself.

Since it's just a web request you can use [LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) or any other HTTP module.

You might alo want to check out the
[ElasticSearch](https://metacpan.org/module/ElasticSearch) and
[ElasticSearch::SearchBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/ElasticSearch::SearchBuilder)
modules which provide a more full perl interface to querying an ElasticSearch database.

Here's a full example in perl using LWP:

```
use JSON qw( encode_json decode_json );
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $ua->post("http://api.metacpan.org/module/_search",
  Content => encode_json({
    query  => { match_all => {} },
    size   => 1000,
    # limit reponse text to just the module names since that's all we want
    fields => ['module.name'],
    filter => {
      and  => [
        { term => { "module.authorized" => 1 } },
        { term => { "module.indexed"    => 1 } },
        { term => { "distribution" => "XML-LibXML" } },
        { term => { "status" => "latest" } }
      ]
    }
  })
);
my @modules =
  # this can be an array (ref) of module names for multiple packages in one file
  map { ref $_ ? @$_ : $_ }
  # the pieces we want
  map { $_->{fields}{'module.name'} }
  # search results
  @{ decode_json($res->decoded_content)->{hits}{hits} };
print join "\n", sort @modules;
```

For more help visit `#metacpan` on `irc.perl.org`,
or check out the wiki at https://github.com/CPAN-API/cpan-api/wiki.

If you explain a little more what you are doing and/or trying to achive you might find other ways to do it.

Comment: Here's a thorough post from the great Tim Bunce where he wanted to do this at a larger scale which led him to create Dist::Surveyor: http://blog.timbunce.org/2011/11/16/whats-actually-installed-in-that-perl-library/